# "Cannot set property 'onclick' of null" in java script

Tags: javascript, onclick, onclicklistener

I have a problem when use `addEventListener` or `onclick` the code is not executed but the typical `onclick` as attribute in html tag is work.

The problem status that I found it when tested my code in the online debugger is

> "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onclick' of null.

```js
function classChange(sectionName, liName) {

  var IDs = ('general-edit-container', 'contloc', 'payment', 'attach', 'course');
  var number = count(IDs);
  for (var i = 0; i < number; i++) {
    if (IDs[i] == sectionName) {
      document.getElementById(sectionName).style.display = "block";
    } else {
      document.getElementById(sectionName).style.display = "none";
    }
  }
  var arr = ('one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five');
  var num = count(arr);
  for (var b = 0; b < num; b++) {
    if (arr[b] == liName) {
      document.getElementById(liName).className = " activebtn";
    } else {
      document.getElementById(liName).className = "";
    }
  }
}
window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById('geneBtn').onclick = function() {
    classChange('general-edit-container', 'one');
    alert('done');
  };
}
```

```html
<li id="one">
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="geneBtn">
    <img width="40px" src="img/person-info.png">
    <h1 id="demo">General Information</h1>
  </a>
</li>
```

Comment: Not getting the same error as you do. Are you sure that piece of HTML is in the DOM at `onload`? Or might it be added at a later point?

Comment: yes, I added "**onload**" later after seen it on the other's question but the error still. I didn't notice the syntax error until seen the first answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var IDs = ('general-edit-container', 'contloc', 'payment', 'attach', 'course');
```

arrays are created by using square braces like so:

```
var IDs = ['general-edit-container', 'contloc', 'payment', 'attach', 'course'];
```

It's unclear how your `count` function is implemented, but instead of using it, you could simply do

```
var number = IDs.length;
```

Comment: Thank you very much the problem is solved with your solution

Comment: @BatoolAlFardan This code might have fixed several problems in your code, but the one that caused the error you mentioned in your question is not one of them.

Comment: @Ivar it did, because ('hello', 'world') evaluates to 'world', which then loops throught every letter of the world and searches for elements with ids 'w', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd' (or 'c', 'o', 'u', 'r', 's', 'e' in his case). That causes element to not be faund, code throws an exception which prevents alert() from being called.

Comment: @StanislovasJanonis The error is "_Cannot set property 'onclick' of null_". The `onclick` is set _before_ the `IDs` are set/the loop is executed, so no, this didn't fix that problem. This error occurs if you try to set `onclick` on an `undefined` value, which can only happen when `document.getElementById('geneBtn')` returns `undefined`, which happens when the element can't be found. That has nothing to do with the errors you fixed in this answer.

Comment: ah wait, you're right, somehow I managed to skip part of the question. Weird :)

Answer (score 0):

This should help you debug your problem.

- Added a check whether element actually exists
- Converted arrays to use square brackets
- Changed count into Array.length

```js
function classChange(sectionName, liName) {
  var IDs = ['general-edit-container', 'contloc', 'payment', 'attach', 'course'];
  var number = IDs.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < number; i++) {
    var section = document.getElementById(IDs[i]);
    if (section === null) {
      alert('There is no element with the id of "' + IDs[i] + '" in the DOM.');
      continue;
    }
    if (IDs[i] == sectionName) {
      section.style.display = "block";
    } else {
      section.style.display = "none";
    }
  }
  var arr = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five'];
  var num = arr.length;
  for (var b = 0; b < num; b++) {
     var listItem = document.getElementById(arr[b])
     if (listItem === null) {
       alert('There is no element with the id of "' + arr[b] + '" in the DOM.');
       continue;
     }    
    if (arr[b] == liName) {
      listItem.className = " activebtn";
    } else {
      listItem.className = "";
    }
  }
}
window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById('geneBtn').onclick = function() {
    classChange('general-edit-container', 'one');
    alert('done');
  };
}
```

```html
<li id="one">
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="geneBtn">
    <img width="40px" src="img/person-info.png">
    <h1 id="demo">General Information</h1>
  </a>
</li>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Mr.Webber your code is more useful and organized. Although  I modified my code and it works well, but your code seems like more organize and useful. I will use it.